# goPersonal is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

i try to direct the user directly to a new component, if the user is already signed in. Unfortunately i receive always the error "goPersonalData is not a function". Maybe someone could help me:

```
ngOnInit() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.goPersonalData();
  } else {


  }
});

}
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
const email = form.value.email;
const password = form.value.password;

this.authService.login(email, password);

}
goPersonalData() {
this.router.navigate(['/personalData']);
 }



  }
```

Comment: I don't know what you do before, but do you think bind your function `goPersonalData()` into your class constructor ?

Comment: this is my constructor   constructor(private router: Router , private authService: AuthService ) { }

Comment: You need to bind your function into your constructor. `this.goPersonalData = this.goPersonalData.bind(this)`